# Alignment works on fiddle but not actual browswer when ran

Tags: html, css

When I run this in jsfiddle it works fine, but when I test run on any browser the alignment is messed up?  The pictures are supposed to be aligned on the left side one on top of the other.

```
<main>
    <h2>Shop at Pacific Trails</h2>

    <h3>Contact Us</h3>

    <p>Required information is marked with an asterisk(*).</p>

    <img class="leftfloat" src="trailguide.jpg" alt="picture of trail 
    guide"/>

    <h3>Pacific Trails Hiking Guide</h3>

    <p>Guided hikes to the best trails around Pacific Trails Resort.  
    Each hike includes a detailed route, distance, elevation change, and 
    estimated time. 187 pages. Softcover. $19.95.</p>

    <form method="post"
    action="http://www.webdevfoundations.net/scripts/cart.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="descl" id="descl" value="Hiking Guide">
    <input type="hidden" name="costl" id="costl" value="19.95">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
    </form>

    <br class="clear">


    <img class="leftfloat" src="yurtyoga.jpg" alt="picture of yoga 
    book"/>

    <h3>Yurt Yoga</h3>

    <p>Enjoy the restorative poses of yurt yoga in the comfort of your 
    own home.  Each post is illustrated with several photographs, an 
    explanation, and a description of the restorative benefits. 206 
    pages. Softcover. $24.95.</p>

    <form method="post"
    action="http://www.webdevfoundations.net/scripts/cart.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="desc2" id="desc2" value="Yurt Yoga">
    <input type="hidden" name="cost2" id="cost2" value="24.95">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
    </form>

    <br class="clear">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5eewf859/

Comment: most of the css is for pages other than this one.  The main css for this page is at the bottom of the css file

Comment: look at each (jsfiddle, and your actual site) in chrome browser with dev tools, and see what's different between the two?

Comment: the second image isnt floating left like its supposed to.  It's not aligning under the first image

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line `float:clear;` in the css. This should read `clear:both;`.

The problem with the fiddle is that there are no images to load, so the alignment issue doesn't show up. But it you were to put actual images in the fiddle, the problem shows there as well. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5eewf859/1/).

Solution: replace `float:clear` with `clear:both`.

```css
body {
  /*background-image: url(background.jpg);*/
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #666666;
  font: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: Georgia, serif;
}

h1 {
  background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 200%;
  height: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #90C7E3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font: Georgia, serif;
}

dt {
  color: #000033;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.resort {
  color: #000033;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: .70em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 700px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

h3 {
  color: #000033;
}

main {
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  display: block;
}

.homehero {
  background-image: url(coast.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.yurthero {
  background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.trailhero {
  background-image: url(trail.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

table {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #3399cc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #3399cc;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #F5FAFC;
}

label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#mySubmit {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

video,
embed {
  float: right;
  margin: 2em;
}

.leftfloat {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
  <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
</nav>



<main>
  <h2>Shop at Pacific Trails</h2>
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>Required information is marked with an asterisk(*).</p>

  <img class="leftfloat" src="https://placehold.it/250x251" alt="picture of trail guide" />

  <h3>Pacific Trails Hiking Guide</h3>
  <p>Guided hikes to the best trails around Pacific Trails Resort. Each hike includes a detailed route, distance, elevation change, and estimated time. 187 pages. Softcover. $19.95.</p>
  <form method="post" action="http://www.webdevfoundations.net/scripts/cart.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="descl" id="descl" value="Hiking Guide">
    <input type="hidden" name="costl" id="costl" value="19.95">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
  </form>

  <br class="clear">


  <img class="leftfloat" src="https://placehold.it/250x252" alt="picture of yoga book" />

  <h3>Yurt Yoga</h3>
  <p>Enjoy the restorative poses of yurt yoga in the comfort of your own home. Each post is illustrated with several photographs, an explanation, and a description of the restorative benefits. 206 pages. Softcover. $24.95.</p>
  <form method="post" action="http://www.webdevfoundations.net/scripts/cart.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="desc2" id="desc2" value="Yurt Yoga">
    <input type="hidden" name="cost2" id="cost2" value="24.95">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
  </form>

  <br class="clear">



</main>



<footer>
  Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort <br>
  <a href="christian@gmail.com">christian@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
```